# How to add text on border with css for input field using React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to create an input box like below,

[image]

using css, however am not able to find anything on how to do the text on border for input fields anywhere at all
I tried using  but am unable to create the input box as shown above.
I am very much stuck here, it would be a great help if anyone could suggest anyway to create an input field like shown above.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The closest it came to my mind is a text box inside a tab control.

Comment: could you please write some example code? @JoseCabreraZuniga

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-material-textfield](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield) library and need some customization. There is a prop `renderLeftAccessory` which can render your left view like `country code` here. Try example code here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  TextField,
  FilledTextField,
  OutlinedTextField,
} from 'react-native-material-textfield';

class Example extends Component {
  fieldRef = React.createRef();

  onSubmit = () => {
    let { current: field } = this.fieldRef;

    console.log(field.value());
  };

  formatText = (text) => {
    return text.replace(/[^+\d]/g, '');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <OutlinedTextField
        label='Phone number'
        keyboardType='phone-pad'
        formatText={this.formatText}
        onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit}
        ref={this.fieldRef}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion but I am writing in React JS, I suppose react native packages are not supported on CRA